# editing a output file to be delimited with a semicolon and the input file is a CSV kornshell

Tags: awk, sed, ksh, aix

My input file is CSV

```
AED,E  ,3.67295,20160105,20:10:00,UAE DIRHAM    
ATS,E  ,10.9814,20160105,20:10:00,AUSTRIAN SHILLINGS    
AUD,A  ,0.71525,20160105,20:10:00,AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR
```

I want to read it in to output it like so

```
EUR;1.127650;USD/EUR;EURO;Cash    
JPY;124.335000;JPY/USD;JAPANESE YEN;Cash    
GBP;1.538050;USD/GBP;BRITISH POUND;Cash
```

actual code :

```
cat $FILE2 | while read a b c d e f
do
    echo $a $c $a/USD $f Cash \
    | awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS =";" } {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' >> my_ratesoutput.csv
```

output:

```
Cash;;;;95 AED/USD UAE DIRHAM    
Cash;;;;14 ATS/USD AUSTRIAN SHILLINGS    
Cash;;;;25 AUD/USD AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR    
Cash;;;;/USD BARBADOS DOLLAR
```

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match input.

Comment: I hope you just want to do the text conversion instead of financial currency conversion.... please check your input and output, is it really want you have and what you are expecting?

Comment: i just want the format to match not the dollar conversions.3 character currency code";" dollar value";" 3 character currency code"/USD"":"name of the currency ";""cash". I want the file to have the fields seperated by a semicolon

Comment: I can not understand how `AED,E  ,3.67295,20160105,20:10:00,UAE DIRHAM ` should be converted into `EUR;1.127650;USD/EUR;EURO;Cash `. When do you want `xxx/EUR` and when `EUR/xxx` ?

Comment: Try something like `while IFS=, read a b c d e f; do ... done`

Answer (score 0):

```
export IFS=","
semico=';'
FILE=rates.csv
FILE2=rateswork.csv
echo $FILE
rm my_ratesoutput.csv
cp -p $FILE $FILE2

sed 1d $FILE2 > temp.csv

mv temp.csv $FILE2
echo "Currency;Spot Rate;Terms;Name;Curve" >>my_ratesoutput.csv

cat $FILE2 |while read a b c d e f
do
   echo $a$semico$c$semico$a/USD$semico$f$semicoCash >> my_ratesoutput.csv
done
```

Comment: Is this the solution that you want (accept it for having the question completed) or do you still have issues?